# How can I generate a FactoryGirl file into an specific folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using rspec with factory_girl but when I run

**rails g rspec:model catalog/product_type**

I get this:

**create  spec/models/catalog/product_type_spec.rb**

**invoke  factory_girl**

**create    spec/factories/catalog_product_type.rb**

but factory_girl doesn't generate the file in the ***catalog*** folder, instead it set  ***catalog*** has part of the file name so I want to generate the factory_girl file just like it is generated in the spec file

Insted of this:

> **create    spec/factories/catalog_product_type.rb**

I want this

> **create    spec/factories/catalog/product_type.rb**

[Attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFIfu.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the default directory for your factories in your `development.rb` configuration file:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.factory_girl dir: 'spec/factories/catalog/'
end
```

`config.generators` is part of Rails can is a common pattern for defining generator paths for other gems/libraries as well.

For more options on FactoryGirl generator config you can see the source here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/lib/generators/factory_girl/model/model_generator.rb

And the docs:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails#configuration

Comment: I did it and now generates the factory_file in the catalogs folder, but still creating the file with the wrong name